# Ruby AASM (Act as State Machine): processing a payment: combining a before callback with a guard

Tags: ruby, state-machine, aasm

Let's assume a very simple `Payment` class like this:

```
class Payment
  include AASM

  aasm do

    state :created
    state :paid
    state :refunded

    event :pay do

      transitions from :created, to :paid

    end

  end

end
```

So one would call `payment.pay` to trigger the payment, making the appropriate API Calls.

It's very important that the transition from `created` to `paid` only happens if the payment actually succeeds.

1) I would assume the API Calls should be put in a `before` callback in the `:pay` event, but that would not halt the transition if the API call was unsuccessful (let's assume the API call does NOT raise an exception, it just returns a status).

2) I then thought that I should combine the `before` callback with a guard; use the `before` callback to call the API, and set it's result on the model (using an `attr_accessor` for instance). Then the guard would only allow it transition from the `created` to `paid` state if the payment was successful.

Is that the idiomatic way of handling such an event transition in a state machine with aasm? I read all stack overflow's questions tagged `aasm` and the gem documentation and still have questions about what's the best way to make these safe transitions.